# how can i make this PCF lookup filter working?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

We have a field on a appointment form which will populate multiple contact based on the below filter by the help of pcf control, our requirement is to select only that contact which are associated with a particular account(lookup field on appointment view) so we have added the additional filter marked in bold but it is not working.

```
let accountid= Xrm.Page.getAttribute('elogic_account').getValue()[0].id;

console.log(accountid); 
return this._context.webAPI.retrieveMultipleRecords(this.props.entityName,`?$select=${this.props.columns}&$filter=contains(${this.props.filterField}, '${newValue}' )and elogic_account eq '${accountid}'* &$top=${this.props.topCount}`) .then(function (results) { return results?.entities; __ })
```

Answer (score 0):

Few obervations/questions.

1. this.props.entityName --> This must be contact entity?
2. e`logic_account eq '${accountid}` --> Should this not be parentcustomerid or accountid field? Reason you are saying give me all contact who have parent as account.
3. `let accountid= Xrm.Page.getAttribute('elogic_account').getValue()[0].id;`
   I believe this does return you account Guid?
4. `contains(${this.props.filterField}, '${newValue}' )` --> I would say remove this filter for time been and try if you get the result.

Below example: if you see there are 2 lookup fields on contact record `accountid` and `parentcustomerid`, so you have to decide what is your filter field

```
Xrm.WebApi.online.retrieveMultipleRecords("contact", "?$select=contactid,_accountid_value,_parentcustomerid_value,fullname&$filter=_parentcustomerid_value eq 2fe32f22-d01d-ea11-80fa-005056936c69").then(
    function success(results) {
        console.log(results);
        for (var i = 0; i < results.entities.length; i++) {
            var result = results.entities[i];
            // Columns
            var contactid = result["contactid"]; // Guid
            var accountid = result["_accountid_value"]; // Lookup
            var accountid_formatted = result["_accountid_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
            var accountid_lookuplogicalname = result["_accountid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname"];
            var parentcustomerid = result["_parentcustomerid_value"]; // Customer
            var parentcustomerid_formatted = result["_parentcustomerid_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
            var parentcustomerid_lookuplogicalname = result["_parentcustomerid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname"];
            var fullname = result["fullname"]; // Text
        }
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
);
```